# Multiple json in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, didselectrowatindexpath

I have maultiple json :

```
http://privatereisen.com/dok/TV/pays/italie/json/chaine0.json
http://privatereisen.com/dok/TV/pays/italie/json/chaine1.json...... etc
```

And a table with different channels. Chaine0 is for the first row from `UITableView`. How can I write in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` json for each channel?

This is how i write for the first json:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://privatereisen.com/"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

[httpClient postPath:@"dok/TV/pays/italie/json/chaine0.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat :@"dok/TV/pays/italie/json/chaine%d.json",indexPath.row];

[httpClient postPath:path parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a collection based on which you populate your `table view`.

The `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method clearly tells you the `indexPath` of the selected cell.

You need to use that to identify the object based on which the cell was populated (If there's a single section, the table view is usually populated based on an `NSArray`, so you can get your object with `id object = self.array[indexPath.row];`)

After you got your object, you do whatever you want with it.

---

Since in your case there's a direct correlation between the `indexPath.row` and your object, you can do:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat :@"dok/TV/pays/italie/json/chaine%@.json",@(indexPath.row)];
```

PS: I recommend using `%@` and converting your `NSInteger` to an `NSNumber` instead of `%d` since `%d` means 32-bit int, but an NSInteger is a 64-bit int on 64-bit devices.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the which row is clicked. For that you have to find the indexPath of that row.

```
NSString *selectingRow=[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Selected Object is %@",selectingRow);
```

Now you can pass any variable to your server(to recognize the specific row details). You have to hit your server and get the details of that row.

Comment: The variable `selectingRow` won't be the `Selected Row`. `indexPath.row` is the selected row. Your variable will be the object associated with the selected row or the selected object for short.

Comment: I am not selecting any variable. I am selecting only row. From row you have to get the variable orderIdClicked = [refinedOrderIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: The log is incorrect `NSLog(@"Selected Row is %@",selectingRow);`. It should be something like `NSLog(@"Selected Object is %@",selectingRow);`